# Scala implicit conversion for object

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-implicits

Suppose that I have the following code snippet:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

sealed trait Command {
  val typeName: String
}

object Command {

  implicit def command2String(implicit c: Command): String =
    c.typeName

}

case object SendMessageCommand extends Command {
  override val typeName: String = "send_message"
}
```

I would like to compare `String` with `Command` descendants without explicit conversion. For example:

```
"sendMessage" == SendMessageCommand
```

Q1: Is it possible in Scala?

Q2: Can I define generic implicit conversion that will convert known type such as String to super class types (like `Command` in my case)?

For example:

```
implicit def string2Command(implicit s: String): Command = {
  case "send_message" => SendMessageCommand
  case _ => // some error thrown
}
```

P.S. I know that it is not idiomatic Scala, but it would be awesome to find out the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible, but not with `==` because Scala support implicit conversion for these cases only: **conversions to an expected type, conversions of the receiver of a selection, and implicit parameters** and hence implicit is not applicable for comparison case. Instead, you have to create a `comparison method` in `Command trait` as below.

```
  sealed trait Command {
    val typeName: String
    def isEqual(c: Command) = c.typeName == this.typeName
  }

  object SendMessageCommand extends Command {
    override val typeName: String = "send_message"
  }

  implicit def stringToCommand(s: String) = new Command {override val typeName: String = s}
  implicit def commandToString(c: Command) = c.typeName

  val strToCmdCompare = "send_message" isEqual SendMessageCommand
  val cmdToStrCompare = SendMessageCommand isEqual "send_message"

  println(strToCmdCompare)    //print true
  println(cmdToStrCompare)    //print true
```

Now, coming to your **second question**, yes its possible to define a generic implicit conversion to convert any given type into another type instance. However, as I am understanding your situation, you have list of objects of Commands, and you want particular command within those objects for given string name. For this, you must have hold of those list of instance.

```
  sealed trait Command {
    val typeName: String
    //This is required for implicit conversion.
    override def toString: String = typeName
  }

  object SendMessageCommand extends Command {
    override val typeName: String = "send_message"
  }
  object AddMessageCommand extends Command {
    override val typeName: String = "add_message"
  }
  object UpdateMessageCommand extends Command {
    override val typeName: String = "update_message"
  }
  object DeleteMessageCommand extends Command {
    override val typeName: String = "delete_message"
  }

  //List of commands.
  implicit val cmds: List[Command] = List(SendMessageCommand, AddMessageCommand, UpdateMessageCommand, DeleteMessageCommand)

  //Convert given type T into type U.
  implicit def convert[T, U](s: T)(implicit list: List[U]): Option[U] = {
    list.find(_.toString == s.toString)
  }
  val res: Option[Command] = "add_message"
  println((res.getOrElse(null) == AddMessageCommand)) //print true
```

Note: as I am comparing two type instance in conversion by converting them into `string`, I have to override `toString` method in Command for this use case. You may need to do so for type `T` as well if it is not string. Furthermore, you can implement you own logic in `convert method` as per required instead of comparing with `toString` conversion.

Comment: Defining such a general implicit conversion as `convert` is not a good idea, generally speaking. If you made it specific to `String`s and `Command`s, you wouldn't need to override `Command#toString` either.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `==`, but you can define your own operator:

```
 case class Foo(s: String) {
   def eq(x: Any) = x match {
     case Foo(str) => str == s
     case str: String => str == s
     cae _ => false
   } 
   def ==: (x: Any) = eq(s)
   def :== (x: Any) = eq(s)
 }

 "bar" ==: Foo("bar") // true
 Foo("bar") :== "bar" // true 
 Foo("bar") ==: Foo("bar") // true
```

This works because of a special trick in scala, making methods, whose names end with a colon bind to the right rather than to the left: `"bar" ==: Foo("bar")` means `Foo("bar").:==("bar")`, not `"bar".:==Foo("bar")`

As for the second question, I am not sure I understand what you are asking ... "Can I define an implicit conversion?" Well, yes, you can :)

Comment: Thank you. Q2: I mean can I define a conversion that will convert not specific type but for its super type. I will update the question if it is not clear enough.

Comment: well, the answer is "yes, you can" ... I still don't understand why you need to ask it . Did you try it, and get some kind of an error?