# scala implicit conversion for case object

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I was referring to the answer posted in [Scala implicit conversion for object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842224/scala-implicit-conversion-for-object)

```
sealed trait Command {
  val typeName: String
  //This is required for implicit conversion.
  override def toString: String = typeName
}

object SendMessageCommand extends Command {
  override val typeName: String = "send_message"
}
object AddMessageCommand extends Command {
  override val typeName: String = "add_message1"
}
object UpdateMessageCommand extends Command {
  override val typeName: String = "update_message"
}
object DeleteMessageCommand extends Command {
  override val typeName: String = "delete_message"
}

//List of commands.
implicit val cmds: List[Command] = List(SendMessageCommand, AddMessageCommand, UpdateMessageCommand, DeleteMessageCommand)

//Convert given type T into type U.
implicit def convert[T, U](s: T)(implicit list: List[U]): Option[U] = {
  list.find(_.toString == s.toString)
}

implicit val convert3: Command => String =
  (v: Command) => v.typeName

val res1:String = UpdateMessageCommand
val res: Option[Command] = "add_message1"
```

I created my new convertor `convert3` which converts Command => String .
The above works , but I am not sure why the user has overidden string for the implicit conversion

```
  //This is required for implicit conversion.
  override def toString: String = typeName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the post:

> Note: as I am comparing two type instance in conversion by converting them into string, I have to override toString method in Command for this use case.

Because it's written for generic `T` and `U` (and they don't have bounds), the author can't call `typeName`.

But honestly defining an implicit conversion like that (`convert`, not `convert3`) is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: The convertor ```implicit val convert3: Command => String =
  (v: Command) => v.typeName``` doesnot have any bounds, it still doesnot work without overriding toString

Comment: Yes, it does. You just need a context which triggers it, e.g. `val x: String = SendMessageCommand` and you'll see. It'll work (and without the converter it won't) whether or not you override `toString`.

Comment: But note it's more usual to write as `implicit def convert3(v: Command): String = v.typeName`.

Comment: Wait, you already have this context. Just remove the `toString` override and the last line from the code in your question and see it still compiles: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/8ItX5lt/0. And if you remove `convert3`, the last line will be an error.